# Is it possible to change CacheModule ttl after application has being started in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, caching, nestjs

I have registered `CacheModule` with specific `ttl` `CacheModule.register({ ttl: 5 * 60 * 60 })`

I want to be able dynamically adjust the `ttl` once application is running.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible, there is a `CacheManager` exported from `@nestjs/common`, where it's used inside of `CacheInterceptor`, little investigate shows that just pass arguments to the `cache-manager`, where `ttl` can be a function, but it's evaluated before passing it to the `store` (`memory` is one of the `cache-manager` story), then inside of it there is a line:

```
var maxAge = (options.ttl || options.ttl === 0) ? options.ttl * 1000 : lruOpts.maxAge;
```

by this line, you can assume that, you probably might do something like:

```
const options = {
  ttl: () =>({ valueOf: () => someVariable })
}
```

Because:

```js
let c = { valueOf: () => 2 }
console.log(100*c);
```

That's only my thoughts, didn't try.

Regards.

Comment: where would you stick that code in to to try it out?

Comment: You mean this options? Here:

```const someVar = 23; CacheModule.register({ ttl: () => ({ someVar })})```

Comment: Say I want to adjust the `ttl` on each request in my services. So sounds like I need to use some global variable ? Do you think the `CacheModule.register` always take the current variable? I have a feeling as it is initialized just once so it won't care it the variable was changed since then. Any thoughts?

Comment: @sreginogemoh `CacheModule.register` at the end doesn't play here, its only the "proxy" to pass args to the `cache-manager`, so depends what you will pass, this will be evaluated. Example of `someVariable` is only concept, it can be anything, fe:

import SomeObject from 'some/path';
const options = {
  ttl: () =>({ valueOf: () => SomeObject })
}

where SomeObject implements a `valueOf ` function.

Comment: But it will live out of the `nest` context, or you might get nest context, and then try to inject it there. There is plenty of solutions, depends of what fit for you.

Comment: What you saying is that if I pass the variable that will be changing dynamically later on the cache-manager always use that variable whatever value it is contained at particular point of time? Please correct me if I am wrong.